# How to use algebraic means to prove this double series identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, generating-functions

How to use algebraic means to prove this double series identity?
\begin{align*}
\color{black}{\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)x^{n}\right]\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}\right]\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)x^{5n}\right]\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{5n}\right]}\\
\color{black}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(k+1\right)\left(l+1\right)\big(x^{2k+10l}+x^{2k+10l+1}+x^{2k+10l+5}+x^{2k+10l+6}\big)}
\end{align*}
Does this identity have a generalized form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x^5)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^5} 
&=\frac{(1+x)(1+x^5)}{(1-x)^2(1+x)^2(1-x^5)^2(1+x^5)^2} \\
&=\frac{(1+x)(1+x^5)}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x^{10})^2}
\end{align}

The RHS is
\begin{align}
(1+x)(1+x^5)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty (k+1)(\ell+1) x^{2k+10\ell}
&= (1+x)(1+x^5)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) (x^2)^k\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty (\ell+1) (x^{10})^\ell \\
&= (1+x)(1+x^5)\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x^{10})^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can use the [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)x^{n} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)x^{5n} = \frac{1}{(1-x^5)^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{n} = \frac{1}{(1+x)}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{5n} = \frac{1}{(1+x^5)}$$

You can get these expansions using the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).

I assume that $|x| < 1$ and $|x^5| < 1$, otherwise the series would be divergent.